# How get the facebook user image in PassportJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, passport.js

I'm using NodeJS with PassportJS. In the profile object there's only some personal info but not the user image.

How to get the picture? What tools do I need?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `graph.facebook.com/v2.2/{user-id}/picture`

Reference from [Facebook api.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/picture)

Comment: Perfect!!, with the URL(graph.facebook.com/v2.2/{user-id}/picture), and   putting user-id the image is displayed. Thanks!!